# problem in loading android sdk with eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I downloaded all the packages of android through 3 to 11 APIs, but when I start the eclipse I found only API 3 to 8.

Actually I downloaded apis 9 to 11 after the completion of last download(3 to 8) and I got message ADB updated. I've given the correct SDK path to eclipse ADT plugin.

I'm on Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: Did you see any warning messages in the installation dialog?

Answer (score 4):

Try updating the tools via Eclipse itself under menu <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Check for Updates</kbd>.